# Call an event based on property value in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid and a button. I want to enable the button only when an entire row is selected. Otherwise it should be disabled.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
             //Here I want to enable the button which is outside the grid.         
         </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried to use binding to button's property IsEnabled?

Comment: In general, this kind of logic is solved by third object to which yo databinds both DataGridRow.IsSelected and Button.IsEnabled. Usually the object is viewmodel, actually

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether using a style trigger is a correct idea to solve your problem.
This issue can be solved using a delegate-event concept in your view model.

Create a property in your datagrid item source whose change raises an event. The handler of the event will in turn would set the button IsEnable property to true/false.

I have created a test application that would help you understand what I want to say.
Download it from : https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxzmpslt1bs0sei/WpfApplication2.rar?dl=0

try this and tell me if it did what you desired.